# React Native Pan Responder X Axis vs Scroll

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

In an effort to learn the `Animated` API and `PanResponder` i've created a component that allows users to drag each list item in a `FlatList` left or right to trigger actions (similar to the google inbox app)

The problem i've encountered is that this seems to override the scrolling in the `FlatList` since the `PanResonder` is immediately triggered. As a temporary solution, i have updated my code so that users need to drag their finger from the edge of the screen to trigger the `PanResponder`. (this is not ideal)

Is there anyway to reliably figure out if the users action is more X than Y and only trigger the `PanResonder` when this is the case, otherwise allowing scroll as usual?

The code for my `PanResponder` below: (I have not included the code for `onPanResponderRelease` since it's not relevant)

```
this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({

    onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,

    onPanResponderTerminationRequest: () => false,

    onPanResponderGrant: (e, gestureState) => {

        if(gestureState.x0 < sideSwipeThresh || gestureState.x0 > this.screenWidth - sideSwipeThresh) {
            this.swipedFromEdge = true;
        } else {
            this.swipedFromEdge = false;
        }

        if(this.swipedFromEdge){
            if(isPanning){
                this.props.isPanning(true)
            }
        }

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem a long while ago, but unfortunately I can not remember correctly how I solved it. I think what I did is to implement onMoveShouldSetPanResponder and check, whether the swipe in dx or dy exceeds a certain threshold. So you could track dx and dy in onMoveShouldSetPanResponder and grant the pan responder or flatlist to handle the touch depending on dx and dy. I hope this helps you with your problem, it's been a while since I touched RN.

Comment: Thanks, good to know im not the only one! i'll try your suggestion :)